# Forward and reverse conversions between vector<Eigen::Vector3f> and Eigen::Matrix3Xf

Tags: c++, eigen

How to convert `vector<Eigen::Vector3f>` to `Eigen::Matrix3Xf` ?

and

inverse operation ?

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<Eigen::Vector3f> x{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}};

Eigen::Matrix3Xf y;

y = x?
```

```
vector<Eigen::Vector3f> x;

Eigen::Matrix3Xf y{{1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}, {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}};

x = y?
```

Comment: are you using a library?

Comment: eigen and vector ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignment `vector` to `Matrix`, use a `Map` (you need to make sure that `x.size()>0`):

```
// Works as constructor or assignment:
Eigen::Matrix3Xf y = Eigen::Matrix3Xf::Map(x[0].data(), 3, x.size());
```

The other way around, you can use the iterator interface of Eigen:

```
// Constructor:
vector<Eigen::Vector3f> x(y.colwise().begin(), y.colwise().end());
// Assignment:
x.assign(y.colwise().begin(), y.colwise().end());
```

Usually, there is no need to copy between both representations, you can use `Eigen::Map` directly in `Eigen` expressions or pass `Eigen` iterators directly to `std` algorithms.